# double to string conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I am using the below code:

```
string.Format("{0:###,###,###,###,###.00}",12005557590928.143);
```

to convert the double value to string.

it gives the output as "12,005,557,590,928.10"

if I change it to

```
string.Format("{0:###,###,###,###,###.##}",12005557590928.143);
```

I get. "12,005,557,590,928.1".

How can I get the output as "12005557590928.143"?

Comment: Here is a link that will show you all the ways to use `string.Format` http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a precision error because of the data type you're using for the number. Try using a fixed point number type (in this case, a `decimal`):

```
string.Format("{0:###,###,###,###,###.###}", 12005557590928.143m);
```

Comment: @Rotem - Interesting. MSDN used to refer to it as fixed point. They're documentation actually still says "Compared to floating-point...".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `string.Format("{0:###,###,###,###,###.000}",12005557590928.143);`
(note the extra zero at the end)

Comment: I don't think he wanted zeros at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(12005557590928.143).ToString("R")
```

The **custom** numeric format strings will never reveal more than 15 decimal digits of a `System.Double`. Consider using `System.Decimal` if you need greater precision.

If your goal is to reveal "hidden" digits of the `Double`, use **standard** numeric format strings `"R"` ("round-trip") or `"G17"` ("general" 17 digits).

Answer (score 1):

Try  with `.ToString("R")`

```
Console.WriteLine((12005557590928.143).ToString("R"));
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/4Z2Oo2).

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write(string.Format("{0:0.000}", (12005557590928.143m)));
```

Comment: this yields `"12005557590928.143"` what about the commas ?

Comment: Can you please explain the suffix 'm' here?

Comment: @UthistranS. The 'm' stands for a decimal. For more information, Jon Skeet has a very good answer on the difference between float, double and decimal on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c